# Semi-logged in/timed out users personalisation

Tags: login, e-commerce, header, timeout

Lets say users session times out and he is logged out. I want to add little piece of personalisation for those users saying:
**Name, not you?**
Issue i am having is that with current layout I already have for not logged in users is:
**Login | Join | Flag v**
And logged in customers are seeing:
**Account  | Log out  |  Flag v**

The rough layout for not logged in:
[image]

Rought layout for logged in:
[image]

Now one of the semi logged out states:
[image]

or:
[image]

Which wording and location would work better for customers who are logged out due timing out? These customers would be prompted personalised login page before entering checkout/their account area.  I dont think having Join/register makes much sense for these customers. Just wondering what approaches there are regarding this issue?

Comment: Personally I always find this feature a little strange/frustrating. eBay and Amazon act as if I'm logged in, but really all they remember is my name, and they ask me to log in when I'm not expecting it. Can you explain what problem this feature is solving? I'm not convinced that "This website I'm logged out of doesn't remember my name" is a problem, especially when remembering the person's name might give them the wrong impression about their state (Logged in vs. not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following the natural path of the User.

For logged out, the natural path would be joining or logging in.
For those who are logged in, the first would be user invocation, then wall the things s/he can do in the system and eventually: leaving it.

So:

1. User not logged in, not remembered:

> Join | Log in
>
> Meaning: Hello stranger. Why don't you join, or if you have an account already, log in?

2. User logged in:

> Hi Dan | Account | Log out
>
> Meaning: Hello Dan. Here is your stuff. Once you are done, you close the door.

3. User logged out automatically, remembered:

> Hi Dan (*not you?*) | *You have been logged out due to inactivity.* Log in
>
> Meaning: Is that you, Dan? We have closed the door because we thought you were not around, please make yourself at home.

As far as User logged out by tapping "Log out" is concerned, s/he could be either forgotten or (so 1.) or remembered (so 3.), depending on how you feel the users' expectations would be.